# QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

*qrc* представлен так

```
<RCC>
   <qresource prefix="/">
       <file>Main.qml</file>
       <file>DialogHelp.qml</file>
       <file>DialogPassword.qml</file>
       <file>DialogHour.qml</file>
       <file>DialogListTrack.qml</file>
       <file>DialogMusic.qml</file>
       <file>ListBox.qml</file>
      <file>DialogSearch.qml</file>
      <file>ButtonCloseControl.qml</file>
  </qresource>
  <qresource prefix="/font">
      <file>font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf</file>
      <file>font/fontawesome.js</file>
  </qresource>
  <qresource prefix="/banner">
      <file>banner/banner.jpg</file>
      <file>banner/Banner.qml</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

В файле *Main* хочу импортировать файл `Banner.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Image {
   source: "qrc:/banner/banner/banner.jpg"
   smooth: true
}
```

импортирую этот файл так:

```
import "qrc:/banner/banner/Banner.qml" as Banner

initialItem: Banner.Image {
   width: rect1.width
   height: rect1.height
}
```

пишет ошибку:

> QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
> qrc:/Main.qml:7 "qrc:/banner/banner/Banner.qml": no such directory
>
> ASSERT: "!isEmpty()" in file /opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 316
> Программа неожиданно завершилась.

делаю в Qt Creator 3.4.2 g++